# QPixmap not displaying using Ubuntu 18

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt, qlabel, qpixmap

Creating a python GUI using PyQt5.  I'm running my code in Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 in a VM.  And I cannot get any image to display using QPixmap in a QLabel widget.

Tried multiple PNG and JPG files. Tried their relative and absolute paths.  Nothing is working.

Added a quick sample code to demonstrate.  When executed, a blank window is opened (see below).  Appreciate any help.

Window Image

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import os, sys

class Main_Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        h1 = QHBoxLayout(self)

        l1 = QLabel(self)
        l1.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.getcwd() +'/image.png'))

        h1.addWidget(l1)
        self.setLayout(h1)

        self.resize(1000,800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window Title')

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(os.getcwd())
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main_Window()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is the path of image.png and output of `print(os.getcwd() +'/image.png')`?

Comment: Everything works in Windows 10

Comment: The images aren't in the current working directory. Note that that is not necessarily the same directory as the one containing the script. If you want to get the latter, use `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the image name inside the double quotes.
eg:

```
l1.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.getcwd() +"/image.png"))
```